# MariaDB 10.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, mariadb

Can you please let me know why MariaDB has not released a Mariadb 10.2 official repository for ubuntu 20.04?  Does that mean that we cannot install Mariadb 10.2 on Ubuntu 20.04? MariaDB 10.2 and Ubuntu 20.04, are they incompatible?

Is that okay if I install MariaDB 10.2 on ubuntu 20.04 from the following official repository?

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] https://mirror.kku.ac.th/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu bionic main'
```

Regards

Comment: The "why" is simple: Few volunteers test older packages with newer releases of Ubuntu. We don't know if MariaDB 10.2 works with Ubuntu 20.04, since nobody has published that they tested it; everybody tested 10.3 instead. You seem to want to join that select group of testers. I suggest trying it in a Virtual Machine to avoid breaking your system. Be sure to record and publish your findings.

Comment: thanks all for sharing your thoughts with me